# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have this error in my code before the `{ (builde:(context,snapshot)`

```dart
buildSearchresult() {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: searchresultfuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgress();
          }
          
          
        });
  }
```

Comment: @HasanAlyazidi can you help me with this please

Answer (score 5):

The `builder` must always return a widget. However, in your code, if the condition `!snapshot.hasData` is not satisfied, the `builder` returns null. So you should return a widget outside this condition:

```dart
buildSearchresult() {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: searchresultfuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgress();
          }
          return Container(); // The widget containing your data
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71177669/10157127).

You are returning widget only when you don't have data.
you need to return widget on every possible case, like

- error
- on data
- no data
- waiting

You can also simplify by returning default widget others state.

```dart
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
 /// return your widget while loadling
 } else if (snapshot.hasError) { 
 /// return your widget based on error
  } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
 /// return your widget while have data
  } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
 /// return your widget while there is no data
  } else {
 /// return  widget
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `return` from your `FutureBuilder()`.
The `return` you have is just for your `if` statement not `FutureBuilder()`.

Use:

```dart
buildSearchresult() {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: searchresultfuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgress();
          }
          return ...     // add this to return something.
          
        });
  }
```

See a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873756/flutter-error-the-body-might-complete-normally-causing-null-to-be-returned) for more info.